# Orthonormal bases with inner products question

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

I am stuck on this problem I have found and was wondering if any one had any ideas. I want to prove, that if $V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space with inner product $\langle,\rangle$, and $R:V \rightarrow V, S:V \rightarrow V$ and $\{e_1,...e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$, then $$\langle Su,v\rangle =\langle u, Rv\rangle$$ if and only if $$Re_j=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle e_j,Se_i\rangle e_i$$

I think you can prove one direction (the forward complication) by working out the matrix for $S$ with respect to a basis, and, nothing that $R$ is the adjoint of $S$, you can follow the usual proof for the form of the adjoint's matrix, and you get the required sum. However, I'm assuming I now need to show a converse direction, and that this is not strong enough to show both sides? If so, how do I do this, starting with sum, I just can't see where to go from there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need no representation of the matrices.  The forward case is just one line. Recall that for any $v\in V$ you know that 
$$v=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle v,e_i\rangle e_i,$$
therefore
$$Re_j=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle Re_j,e_i\rangle e_i
=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle e_j,Se_i\rangle e_i.$$
For the converse you only need to show $\langle Su,v\rangle =\langle u, Rv\rangle$ for $u,v\in\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$:
\begin{align}\langle e_k,Re_j\rangle&=\bigl\langle e_k,\sum_{i=1}^n \langle e_j,Se_i\rangle e_i\bigr\rangle\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle e_j,Se_i\rangle\langle e_k,e_i\rangle\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle e_j,Se_i\rangle\delta_{ki}\\
&=\langle e_j,Se_k\rangle\\
&=\langle Se_k,e_j\rangle.
\end{align}

Comment: But $\langle Su,v\rangle= \langle v,Su\rangle$ is not always true.

Comment: Clearly not, but excuse my blindness: where did I (wrongly) use that?

Comment: Last line?${}{}$

Comment: I was wrong.  As it not true in general that $\langle Su,v\rangle=\langle u,Sv\rangle$ the inner product is symmetric, so $\langle e_j,Se_k\rangle=\langle Se_k, e_j\rangle$ for a real vector space -- I was assuming that.  Otherwise the claim seems to be wrong.

Comment: Yes, OP needs to clarify the question. I got stuck on the same issue.